# What are the strategies to send and retry a delayed API call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, asynchronous

I have a customer-facing website that runs a Ruby on Rails app. Users place orders and they are synced using a series of background rake tasks to the internal ERP system. Every 30 minutes.

We are rebuilding internal systems, as RoR API style app, so web application would basically just send api calls to the internal application when an order is saved . Using something like ActiveResource or ROAR & Delayed Job or something else.

However if internal API goes down for some reason - what are a good strategies to save that customer order on the web server, and then sync it to API when it becomes available? It's kind of similar to what happens on the iPhone / Android - where it can save info locally and sync it later to the cloud API. Except client is a RoR server application. Are there ready made solutions for this? Or should I implement my own "Save to local DB -> sync to API asynchronously when it comes back" type solution?

- Web Application: RoR + jQuery basic CRUD type app, nothing fancy.
  Sits in a public cloud.
- Internal API: - RoR + Trailblazer API, using MariaDB
  cluster sits in in-house Data Center, behind firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there ready made solutions for this?

No.

> Or should I implement my own "Save to local DB -> sync to API asynchronously when it comes back" type solution?

Yes. It's a relatively straight-forward mini-project. I did it yesterday, in fact. Took only a few hours.

For local storage, I use postgresql (I host on Heroku).

I use an `NfpAdmin::ServiceRequest` record to keep track of the results of each transaction attempt. It looks something like this:

```
  # == Schema Information
  #
  # Table name: nfp_admin_service_requests
  #
  #  id               :integer          not null, primary key
  #  service_name     :string
  #  status           :string           default("created")
  #  percent_complete :integer          default(0)
  #  details          :jsonb            not null
  #  created_at       :datetime         not null
  #  updated_at       :datetime         not null
  #

  class NfpAdmin::ServiceRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :details, HashSerializer
    validates :service_name,
              :details,
              presence: true
  end
```

I run a nightly job using CloudAMQP and pull (using my real `service_name`, naturally):

```
  NfpAdmin::ServiceRequest.where(service_name: 'foo').where.not(status: 'complete')
```

In the `jsonb` column (`details`), I keep track of every attempted transaction for that service request, outcomes, error messages, etc.

Currently, I receive push messages from the remote API (a third party) and do pull requests. The API allows for updates from my system, but my use cases don't call for that yet.

I run a series of my own API web services in which I do 2-way data exchange.

Comment: Thanks. What did you use for local storage? And how did you sync: 1-way or 2-ways?

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for posting an example. It's nice to see your idea, validated by another person :-)

Comment: Sure thing. Please feel free to accept the answer if it floats your boat.